# SQL get top 5 id's with the highest 'amount' value

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

`id | username | password | amount`

Now, I want the id's of the top 5 poeople with the highest `amount`. I searched some around, but I couldn't really find what I need. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What about if 7 people are all tied with the same highest amount?  What happens then?  Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

use Limit (if your dbms  `mysql` and `postgre`)

```
select * from t
order by amount desc
limit 5
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: ... Or SQLite :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :)

Comment: That gives me this (in order); `8` `8` `7` `69` `6`. But as you know, 69 has to be first

Answer (score 0):

this will work (if its oracle):

```
select * from table_name order by desc amount where rownum<=5
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 * from tbl order by amount desc
```